# Microsoft Planner - Expand Details Returning Null

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been trying to extract the details of task to also get the description when retrieving all of the tasks in a bucket. I've tried several query parameters. With `$expand=details` I see that there is an extra node in the response, but it is always `null`. This is true for any expand query parameter that I provide.

Here is the URL I am attempting:

`/v1.0/planner/buckets/{BucketId}/tasks?$expand=details`

I've attempted this with the `/beta/` endpoint as well with the same result. See below for the result I am receiving:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.plannerTask)",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "***"
        ",
        "createdBy": {
            "user": {
                "displayName": null,
                "id": "***"
            }
        },
        "planId": "***",
        "bucketId": "***",
        "title": "Name",
        "orderHint": "***",
        "assigneePriority": "***",
        "percentComplete": 0,
        "startDateTime": "2017-09-15T12:00:00Z",
        "createdDateTime": "2017-09-15T23:33:10.905638Z",
        "dueDateTime": null,
        "hasDescription": true,
        "previewType": "description",
        "completedDateTime": null,
        "completedBy": null,
        "referenceCount": 0,
        "checklistItemCount": 0,
        "activeChecklistItemCount": 0,
        "appliedCategories": {
            "category2": true
        },
        "assignments": {
            "***": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
                "assignedBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "displayName": null,
                        "id": "***"
                    }
                },
                "assignedDateTime": "2017-09-15T23:33:10.905Z",
                "orderHint": ""
            }
        },
        "conversationThreadId": null,
        "id": "LeURQ5hVvU2tAP7fbbtaiWUANHup",
        "details": null
    }],
}
```

Notice that the details result is null, however, this task does have a description so should have some detail. How should I go about extracting the details of a task, hopefully without having to make multiple calls back to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding details objects and general purpose expansions are currently not supported in the Planner API. Details objects need to be read by separate queries, although the requests can be [batched](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching). Task object contains properties to indicate whether the details object has any relevant information (e.g. *hasDescription*, *referenceCount*, *activeChecklistItemCount*, *checklistItemCount*, and *previewType*), so that unnecessary reading of details objects can be avoided. Other child objects (e.g. task board ordering data) can be expanded with queries that only select *id* property from the task, however only one type of task board formatting can be expanded in a single query.

You can provide feedback about Planner and Planner API functionality [here](https://planner.uservoice.com/forums/330525-microsoft-planner-feedback-forum).